# saving user uploaded image in flask using Pillow

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

i have a problem with saving user uploaded image to specific directory using Pillow i can save it in root folder but when i use a path i get Key Error

i use this function for saving photo

```
import os
from PIL import Image


def upload_photo(post_image, filename):

    with Image.open(post_image) as new_image:
        image = new_image.resize((600, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(os.path.join("../static/upload"), filename)
```

i get image data from form:

```
post_image = form.img.data
filename = secure_filename(post_image.filename)
```

and this is flaskforom that io get the image from html:

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(FlaskForm):
    img = FileField("Upload Blog Image", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

i get this error :

```
File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2419, 
in save
    save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
KeyError: '1.JPG'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both /tmp and /static/uploads/.., are absolute paths. And my code is looking in the / folder instead of looking in my project's folder. I should use the absolute path to point at my folder /path/to/my/project/static/uploads/.. or use a path relative to the code being executed such as ./static/uploads.

I can also use the following snippet to generate the absolute path in config file

```
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath

UPLOADS_PATH = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static/uploads/..')
```

then use :

```
def upload_photo(post_image, filename):
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    with Image.open(post_image) as new_image:
        image = new_image.resize((600, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(os.path.join(basedir, app.config['UPLOADS_PATH'], filename))
```